# Python selenium code is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Why the looping is not working after opening the first element as per the xpath ?
And i am getting the below exception

> ```
>  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>  locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"//[@id='searchresults']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"}
>  Stacktrace:
> at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/home/appdata/local/temp/tmpeglp49/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10723)
> at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/home/appdata/local/temp/tmpeglp49/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10732)
> at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/home/appdata/local/temp/tmpeglp49/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12614)
> at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/home/appdata/local/temp/tmpeglp49/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12619)
> at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/home/appdata/local/temp/tmpeglp49/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12561)
> ```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from texttable import len
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://jobs.ericsson.com/search/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[type="text"][id="keywordsearch-q"]').send_keys('Python')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="btn"][type="submit"]').click()
i=len("//*[@id='searchresults']/tbody/tr/td")
for j in range(1,i+1):
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchresults']/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]"%j).click()
   print driver.find_element_by_id("job-title").text
   driver.back()
   continue
```

Question 2:
Why the length of the list is getting displayed as 12 but they have only 5 herf elements in it ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from texttable import len
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get('https://jobs.ericsson.com/search/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[type="text"][id="keywordsearch-q"]').send_keys('Python')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="btn"][type="submit"]').click()
#currenturl = driver.current_url
pages=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[rel="nofollow"]')
print pages
print 'Its working'
pages1=[]
for page1 in pages:
  pages1.append(page1.get_attribute('href'))
  print int(len(pages1))
```

Question 3:
How to get the elements under html tags

a.How to get the 1-25 and 104 separately under the b tag ?

Please refer the URL: https://jobs.ericsson.com/search/?q=Python (result section getting displayed at the bottom of the page)

```
<div class="paginationShell clearfix" lang="en_US" xml:lang="en_US">
<div class="pagination well well-small">
<span class="pagination-label-row">
<span class="paginationLabel">
 Results 
 <b>1 – 25</b>
   of 
 <b>104</b>
 </span>
```

b.How to get the Job id from the html ?

```
 <div class="job">
<span itemprop="description">
<b>Req ID:</b>
 128378
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: in python you need to intent your code ...

Comment: selenium does not find the element

Comment: i dont think so then i would have received intent error right?. Then why i am getting no such element exception error ?

Comment: I'm quite sure that there are no elements with `id='searchresults'`

Comment: What are trying to do? Click each entry in found jobs list?

Comment: If that is the case why first element alone getiting opened and coming back to search results page

Comment: Yes try trying to opening the links  and getting their title after opening that

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```
for job in range(len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('jobTitle-link'))):
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('jobTitle-link')[job].click()
    print driver.find_element_by_id("job-title").text
    driver.back()
```

Comment: Tested this answer and it work upto `Software Test Engineer (Intern)` posting after that throws exception: `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"job-title"}`

Comment: try to increase wait time- `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help you, but based on my own experience, I typically run into this error when my page hasn't fully loaded. Adding a `time.sleep(1)` before searching for the element *usually* fixes the problem for me (if the code is correct).

```
import time

#Skip your other code

for j in range(1,i+1):
   time.sleep(1)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchresults']/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]"%j).click()
   print driver.find_element_by_id("job-title").text
   driver.back()
   continue
```

Comment: I am not sure why people down vote this question. Is this question is not that much clear?

Comment: People like to see what you've already tried. You posted your problem and ask "why isn't this working?". Seems like people generally don't respond well when you don't explicitly show what you've tried to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works, the idea is not to click on each link rather store the url in a list and then navigate to it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from texttable import len
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://jobs.ericsson.com/search/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[type="text"][id="keywordsearch-q"]').send_keys('Python')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="btn"][type="submit"]').click()

#To further process preserve the current url    
currenturl = driver.current_url
#Get all the elements by class name
jobs  = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('jobTitle-link')
jobslink = []
#Get hyperlink urls from the jobs elements
#This way we avoid clicking each link and going back to the previous page
for job in jobs:
    jobslink.append(job.get_attribute('href'))
#Get each element page  
for job in jobslink:
    driver.get(job)
    print driver.find_element_by_id("job-title").text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me whats wrong with my code.